# AssertionError occurs when posting using django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

AssertionError occurs when posting using django rest framework
The process before an error occurs is this

1. I set the url pattern, view and serializer class

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from . import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('post' , views.PostViewSet)
# print("router.urls : " , router.urls)

urlpatterns = [
    path('public/' , views.PublicPostListAPIView.as_view()),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

view

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from .serializers import PostSerializer
from .models import Post


class PublicPostListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
   queryset = Post.objects.filter(is_public=True)
   serializer_class = PostSerializer

class PostViewSet(ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Post.objects.all()
   serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from instagram.models import Post

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = get_user_model()
      fields = ['username','email']


class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   author = AuthorSerializer()
   
   class Meta:
      model = Post
      fields = [
         'pk',
         'author',
         'message',
         'created_at',
         'updated_at',
         'is_public',

      ]
```

2. Request to the address below

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/
```

3.posting

[image]

4.error occured like below

[image]

thanks for let me know how to fix it

Comment: set `read_only` in serializer as **`AuthorSerializer(read_only=True)`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's assuming to save the `author` details you provided in your `PostSerializer`. You can have your own create() method like this -

```
def create(self, validate_data):
    data = validated_data
    author = data.get('author')
    # You can use author details here
    data.pop('author')
    return Post.objects.create(**data)
```